# Select all if no subset is present, otherwise select subset

Tags: mysql, select, join

Ok here's my problem. Assume a customer has access to a number of regions defined in a CustomerRegions table:

```
CustomerRegionID | CustomerID | RegionID
----------------------------------------
               1 |          1 |        1
               2 |          1 |        2
```

Assume that customer 1 has three users 1, 2, and 3. For each user we can specify to which of the CustomerRegions they have access via a table UserRegions:

```
UserRegionID | UserID | CustomerRegionID
----------------------------------------
           1 |      1 |                1
           2 |      1 |                2
           3 |      2 |                2
```

So user 1 will have access to both Customerregions and user 2 will only have access to CustomerRegion 2.

If there are UserRegions specified for a given user then only those CustomerRegions are present in the result set, but if no UserRegions are specified for a given user then all CustomerRegions are present in the result. I want to get all accessible regions per user of a given customer. The result I am looking for is something like this:

```
CustomerID | UserID | RegionID
------------------------------
         1 |      1 |        1
         1 |      1 |        2
         1 |      2 |        2
         1 |      3 |        1
         1 |      3 |        2
```

My question is can this be done in a single query and how?

Edit:
I seem to have it working now:

```
SELECT CustomerID, 
    UserID, 
    RegionID
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN customerregions ON customerregions.CustomerID = users.CustomerID 
LEFT JOIN userregions ON userregions.UserID = users.UserID AND userregions.CustomerRegionID = customerregions.CustomerRegionID 
LEFT JOIN regions ON regions.RegionID = customerregions.RegionID 
WHERE (userregions.UserID IS NOT NULL 
    OR (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM userregions WHERE userregions.UserID = users.UserID) = 0)
    AND CustomerID = 1
```

The extra count query in the where seems to do the trick. Thanks @Pablo Martinez for your help. However if someone knows of a better way to do this please let me know.

Comment: table structure is so confusing

Answer (score 0):

I'm aggre with @diEcho, the table structure is very confusing

have you try to do a join?

```
Select CustomerID, UserID, RegionID 
    from UserRegions join CustomerRegion 
         on  CustomerRegion.CustomerRegionID=UserRegions.CustomerRegionID  
    where customerID=1
```

Comment: Yes I have tried that, but it is only part of the solution. This gives the regions accessible to users 1 and 2, but user 3 is left out. User for whom no userregions are specified should have access to all customer regions.

Comment: Then use a OUTHER JOIN (left or right, it depends) with table users to select all the users. Users without userregions will be NULL